# How can i override "entity" custom form type used by symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am making my own custom form type which i extend from entity. like this

```
public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'gender';
    }
```

Now in the customform field i display the form with this

```
{% for child in form %}
               {{ form_widget(child) }}
```

So it means , i get the collection of forms based on no. of entities received from query.

now for each form , i have `label , value` stored in `vars` variable.

Now is there any way that i can store one extra variable like category_id in those vars. so that i can have diff value for each child of the form

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the buildView method:

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars = array_replace($view->vars, array(
        'yourfield' => 'yourvalue'
    ));
}
```